# What was the purpose of "sugar coating" the last episode of the second season of "The Good Doctor"?

Tags: ending, the-good-doctor

The oldest trick in the book of a tv show director is to create cliffhangers: if the viewers will be anxious to know "what happens next", the show will live to the next season.

Yet the last episode of the second season of ["The Good Doctor"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6470478/) TV show - *Trampoline* - seems to solve all the problems that have arisen through the season:

> Dr Glassman not only is cured of cancer but also finds love; Murphy lives happily with his friend and has a chance for a romantic relationship; Melendez and Lim change their relationship from "rivals" to "lovers" and finally director of the hospital decides to fire a senior surgeon just to save a (previously disliked) resident.

It sounds so sweet that it could give your diabetes...

There are two reasons for such treatment that I can think of:

1. The show ends - all the plotlines are finished, "and they lived happily ever after" screen is displayed. Everyone moves to new projects.
2. The show will be picked up "X months later", often under new management, often completely changing the direction of the show.

Which one was it? Or maybe it was something different?

Comment: [The Good Doctor Renewed for Season 3](https://tvline.com/2019/02/05/the-good-doctor-renewed-season-3-abc/)

Comment: "if the viewers will be anxious to know "what happens next", the show will live to the next season." That's not really how it works. Cliffhangers may be a good way to get current viewers to return for the next season (though I have my doubts about that), but cancellation is generally based on past performance; ending on a cliffhanger doesn't increase your chances of being renewed if the show's viewing figures have been poor.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, I have seen it used to try to strong arm another season, though unsuccessfully (see Alf)